# How to hide a class if any element gets clicked inside of it?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div id="ad-container" class="overlay">
                <ins onclick="hideGFeedback()" id="overlay-ad" class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:500px;height:60px;"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-2199974740270676"
     data-ad-slot="9684342380"></ins>
     <script>
     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
     </script>
</div>
```

```
    const ad = document.getElementById("ad-container");
    ad.addEventListener('click', e => {
      console.log("test");
      ad.style.opacity = 0;
    })
```

This code will only work, if I click on the id "ad-container" itself.
But how can you make the whole div invisiable just by clicking on ANYTHING inside that id?

I don't know any solution because I can't find any answers

Answer (score 0):

You could do it as follows :

```
// this will Listen for clicks on the entire window
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  event.target.style.opacity = 0
});
```